# Nested flexbox image with same size container div

Tags: html, css, flexbox, aspect-ratio

I am having issues with a nested flexbox container with an image inside of it. I need the image to maintain its 16x9 ratio always and would like the parent (or another div) to always be the exact size of the image, as I am using its coordinates to create a laser pointer feature and send it to other users.

I currently have the following Code:

```css
#container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 2rem 2rem;
}
#container > div {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#container img {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1600x900/000000/fff">
    </div>
</div>
```

The #inner div and image match size when the #container is wider than the image:
[image]
However, when the image is full width, the #inner div is taller than the image:
[image]

Removing the #inner height works for the smaller widths, however the image then blows out of the container as the screen gets wider:
[image]

I have also tried some other solutions, such as adding `object-fit: contain;` to the image, and using a ratio-class with a padding-top of 56.25%, but can't seem to get any of these solutions to be fully responsive.

Any ideas are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

If you set your inner div as display inline block, it will always be the same size as the child image:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container > div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  font-size: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

as in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/nzs21bem/
Is this what you are looking for?

---

---

You need to add some styles to your image so the ratio is preserved.
And display the image as a block element instead of the default inline style,
which has some padding to it.

```css
.imgblock {
  background: red;
  margin: 30px;
}

.imgblock img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.imgblock1 img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgblock imgblock1">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1600x900/000000/fff">
</div>
```

That should make the parent the same size as the child image.
As you can see the difference in these 2 examples: https://jsfiddle.net/no1rqx6f/

Answer (score 0):

If I get the idea correctly should be like this.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#inner img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1600x900/000000/fff">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check this if it is still relevant for you.

Comment: Hi, this works for when the image is shorter than the container, however the image expands beyond the #container div as the screen becomes wider.